# When Moving from .NET 4.x to .NET Core 7 should I change the UserManager class to a UserService and in Program.cs and do AddScoped<UserService> etc

Tags: c#, .net-core, service, architecture, 3-tier

I am moving from .NET 4.x to .NET Core 7 and in the 4.x project I have a 3-Tier architecture; BLL, DAL, UI. In my BLL I have managers like UserManager, BasketManager etc.

I am trying to understand what should change in order to take advantage of the .NET Core 7 performance gains through it's architecture, and basically code the .NET Core 7 way.

Fundamentally, should these managers be changed to services so that they are added in the Program.cs using AddScoped?

I have read a lot of the .NET Core 7 documentation but have not seen any examples where I can see a .NET 4.x application and then see what that same application looks like when migrated to .NET Core 7.

Comment: You are talking about a more current version of Asp.Net Core and its dependency injection framework? And you are currently in a state of not using DI? Or what kind of app you have your 3-Tier architecture in?

Comment: Frankly: We have _no idea_ what a "Manager" in your context even _is_ (nor what it does, what its relations and responsibilities are). Some people would already shudder at the mention of a "manager" since that naming often is indicative of a class that does way too much. That being said: Maybe take a step back and use the opportunity to question a little more of the design you currently have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `UserManager`, `BasketManager` etc are custom classes, then you should be able to keep them just as they are when migrating to .net core. Unless you are using the deprecated APIs, your .net framework code should work fine in .Net 7. But it really depends on your type of application and what dependencies you have.

The `AddScoped` is part of a "Dependency injection" framework, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection. Asp.net core applications uses this by default, so you might want to rewrite your asp.net application to follow the new model to keep things simple and consistent. See [Upgrade from ASP.NET Framework to ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/proper-to-2x/?view=aspnetcore-7.0) for details.

But you can also use Dependency injection in desktop applications, even .net framework applications. I tend to like using Dependency injection, but it can be difficult to retrofit an existing application to use it. But desktop applications do not force you to use any specific architecture, so it is probably easier to make as few changes as possible when migrating, and introduce dependency injection as a separate change.